# Zend Framework: How to render a different action?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-controller

I have two actions that are essentially identical, but need different URLs. Normally I would use `_forward()` to render the other action:

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function actionOneAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('action-two');
    }

    public function actionTwoAction()
    {
        $this->view->foobar = 'foobar';
    }
}
```

However, I have some code the is happening in `preDispatch()` that I only want to execute once:

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        //execute this only once before actionOne or actionTwo, but not both
    }

    public function actionOneAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('action-two'); //this won't work because preDispatch() will get called a second time
    }

    public function actionTwoAction()
    {
        $this->view->foobar = 'foobar';
    }
}
```

So I thought maybe I could simply call the function directly, like this:

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        //execute this only once before actionOne or actionTwo, but not both
    }

    public function actionOneAction()
    {
        $this->actionTwoAction(); //execute the same code as actionTwoAction()
    }

    public function actionTwoAction()
    {
        $this->view->foobar = 'foobar';
    }
}
```

But now Zend Framework is complaining about not being able to find the `action-one.phtml` view script. I don't want to render actionOne's view script. I want to render actionTwo's view script. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `render()` seems to do the trick:

```
public function actionOneAction()
{
    $this->actionTwoAction(); //execute the same code as actionTwoAction()
    $this->render('action-two'); //renders the same view as actionTwoAction()
}
```